# Manipulate multiple divs with different id using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Lets say I have large number html elements with different id's that I want to repeatedly change the style of in my controller (for spectrum visualisation). What is the easiest way to do this (The angular way) without having to write repeating HTML code like

```
<div id="spectrumWrapper">
    <div class="stapleWrapper">
        <div id="sp_1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="stapleWrapper">
        <div id="sp_2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="stapleWrapper">
        <div id="sp_3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="stapleWrapper">
        <div id="sp_4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="stapleWrapper">
        <div id="sp_5"></div>
    </div>
    //.. And so on
</div>
```

In my .js file i have

```
var sp = []
for(var i = 1; i < 41; i++)
   sp[i] = document.getElementById('sp_' + i);
//Some Calculations
for(var i = 1; i < 41; i++)
 sp[i].style.height = '' + 50*vecAverageAmp[i-1] +'px';
```

This works fine, but my .html file is very long. Maybe I can use `ng-repeat` in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **ng-repeat** in the below manner and dynamically adding unique ID's based on the index.

```
<div id="spectrumWrapper">
            <div name="stapleWrapper" ng-repeat="data in dataList">
                <p id="sp_{{$index}}">{{data}}</p>
            </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n69vq4o0/2/).

I hope this is what you are trying.

Thanks.

Comment: In example `stapleWrapper` is just class name, not `id`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the next:

```
<div id="spectrumWrapper">
    <div class="stapleWrapper" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div id="sp_{{$id}}">{{item.name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in controller you can specify your array of repeated elements:

```
.controller('someCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {name: 'Name1', value: '1'},
        {name: 'Name2', value: '2'},
        {name: 'Name3', value: '3'},
    ];
}]);
```

The idea is in adding `{{$id}}` in the `id` attribute. ng-repeat perform unique `$id`'s for every `ng-repeate`'d element.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/HBq5sqD20e0p8V5i5KW8?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Why not dynamically generate the DIV's?

You can do it in Javascript using the createElement function (and then appending the node to the document.body), but I'd probably do it in PHP/ASP or some other server-side language.

As an aside, you shouldn't usually use an ID more than once - instead of , you may wish to use